# Can't edit FileZilla Server.xml file programatically in Windows 7 using C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, windows-7, filezilla

I have using filezilla[version 0.9.39 beta] with my C# windows Form Application in Windows 7.So, I have added users and corresponding shared directory programatically in C:\Program Files\FileZilla Server\FileZilla Server.xml file.But when i open the Filezilla Server Interface and see the users list on the right hand side box, it never displays the users list that are added on the above mentioned file.[see attached image]

[image]

I have also turn off the UAC settings in windows 7.

How do i add users programatically in filezilla server.xml file.

Please guide me to get out of this issue?

Thanks & Regards,
P.SARAVANAN

Comment: do you call "FileZilla Server.exe" /reload-config after adding the users?

Comment: @Sam1 :Sorry I did not do it programatically.I just Opened the filezilla server interface manually...

Comment: @sam1 do i need to reload the config programatically after adding the users?

Comment: yes reload it programatically.

Comment: @Sam1 : thanks Sam. Can you help me to add it programatically?How to do it?

Comment: start a process and pass the above command as argument. here is an example http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25983/How-to-Execute-a-Command-in-C

Comment: @Sam1 : Oh ok ok Thanks sam... let u know

Comment: @Sam1:  I have invoked by using Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\\Program Files\\FileZilla Server\\FileZilla Server.exe"; p.Start();p.Close(); How do i invoke reload-config command

Comment: p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\\Program Files\\FileZilla Server\\FileZilla Server.exe /reload-config"

Comment: @sam1 :Sorry sam i already tried...it throws "The system cannot find the file specified" error message at runtime

Comment: run the  /reload-config as argument i.e. p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/reload-config"; if that doesnt work try this p.StartInfo.FileName = ""C:\\Program Files\\FileZilla Server\\FileZilla Server.exe" /reload-config"

Comment: or if above dont work try this : System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe","/C "+fileZillaPath + "\\\"FileZilla Server.exe\" /reload-config");

Answer (score 2):

Do this after adding a user:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe","/C "+fileZillaPath + "\\\"FileZilla Server.exe\" /reload-config");
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly well when launched from the command line, +1

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small correction :

```
string pathtofilezilla = @"C:\Program Files\FileZilla Server";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/C \"" + pathtofilezilla + "\\FileZilla Server.exe\" /reload-config");
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are entered the correct tags! I had the same issue and the problem was only the " character. I using this method for my SQL database and FileZilla user registration

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE users SET status = 1 WHERE status=0;", kapcsolat);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //folyamat();
        string hely = @"C:\xampp\FileZillaFTP\FileZilla Server.xml";
        try
        {
            StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(hely, false);
            wr.WriteLine("<FileZillaServer>");
            wr.WriteLine("      <Settings>");
            wr.WriteLine("      <Item name=\"Admin port\" type=\"numeric\">14147</Item>");
            wr.WriteLine("    </Settings>");
            wr.WriteLine("  <Groups />");
            wr.WriteLine("  <Users>");
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
            {
                DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\\FTPUsers\" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
                wr.WriteLine(" <User Name=\"" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value + "\">");
                wr.WriteLine("      <Option Name=\"Pass\">" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value + "</Option>");
                wr.WriteLine("      <Option Name=\"Group\"></Option>");
                wr.WriteLine("      <Option Name=\"Bypass server userlimit\">0</Option>");
                wr.WriteLine("       <Option Name=\"User Limit\">0</Option>");
                wr.WriteLine("      <Option Name=\"IP Limit\">0</Option>");
                wr.WriteLine("      <Option Name=\"Enabled\">1</Option>");
                wr.WriteLine("      <Option Name=\"Comments\"></Option>");
                wr.WriteLine("      <Option Name=\"ForceSsl\">0</Option>");
                wr.WriteLine("   <IpFilter>");
                wr.WriteLine("      <Disallowed />");
                wr.WriteLine("      <Allowed />");
                wr.WriteLine("  </IpFilter>");
                wr.WriteLine("  <Permissions>");
                wr.WriteLine("      <Permission Dir=\"C:\\FTPUsers\\" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value + "\">");
                wr.WriteLine("      <Option Name=\"FileRead\">1</Option>");
                wr.WriteLine("      <Option Name=\"FileWrite\">1</Option>");
                wr.WriteLine("      <Option Name=\"FileDelete\">1</Option>");
                wr.WriteLine("      <Option Name=\"FileAppend\">1</Option>");
                wr.WriteLine("      <Option Name=\"DirCreate\">1</Option>");
                wr.WriteLine("      <Option Name=\"DirDelete\">1</Option>");
                wr.WriteLine("      <Option Name=\"DirList\">1</Option>");
                wr.WriteLine("      <Option Name=\"DirSubdirs\">1</Option>");
                wr.WriteLine("      <Option Name=\"IsHome\">1</Option>");
                wr.WriteLine("      <Option Name=\"AutoCreate\">0</Option>");
                wr.WriteLine("    </Permission>");
                wr.WriteLine("  </Permissions>");
                wr.WriteLine("<SpeedLimits DlType=\"0\" DlLimit=\"10\" ServerDlLimitBypass=\"0\" UlType=\"0\" UlLimit=\"10\" ServerUlLimitBypass=\"0\">");
                wr.WriteLine("              <Download />");
                wr.WriteLine("          <Upload />");
                wr.WriteLine("      </SpeedLimits>");
                wr.WriteLine("</User>");
            }
            wr.WriteLine("  </Users>");
            wr.WriteLine("</FileZillaServer>");
            wr.Close();
```